# How to break out column names in MySQL similar to MS SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Is there a way to have MySQL break out the individual column names and have them pre-written in your query similar to the "script>table as" function in MS SQL Server?

My workaround has been using "describe 'table'" in MySQL and copying the columns into the query and adding commas, but there has to be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Show create table yourtablename

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks but this doesn't list out the column names in the text field for me to edit.

Comment: Have you tried construction the query using the information_schema.columns table? I'm no MySql pro, but I bet you could create a procedure that takes a table name and generates the select query.

Answer (score 0):

From MYSQL Workbench: Right click on a table then select '**Send to SQL Editor->Select All Statement**'

[image]